# shows an error when I try to send a file to the node.js

Tags: java, android-studio, retrofit

I'm doing a project that has to send files to the node.js server, but when I upload to send this error appears.

```
2020-03-20 11:39:32.289 11524-11524/com.example.note I/System.out: java.io.FileNotFoundException: content:/com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/2767 (No such file or directory)
```

**CODE:**

```
               RequestBody dateTimeRequest = RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, String.valueOf(note.getDateTime()));
           RequestBody titleRequest = RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, note.getTitle());

           File mediaFile = new File(new File(media).getPath());

           Uri uri = Uri.parse(media);

           RequestBody fileRequest = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext().getContentResolver().getType(uri))),
                   mediaFile);

           MultipartBody.Part file = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("media", mediaFile.getName(), fileRequest);


           call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.uploadMedia(dateTimeRequest, titleRequest, file);
       }

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Note>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Note> call, Response<Note> response) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Note> call, Throwable throwable) {

                System.out.println(throwable);
            }
        });
```

I went to see on the net how to solve on the net but when I put in my code or the error or null

Comment: Are you sure the file `com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/2767`exists?

Comment: @donquih0te i pick a picture from my storage and it show on my imageView so the file exists

Comment: There's no extension (PNG, JPG, or JPEG etc) for the file you picked. I don't know how it shows on your ImageView

Comment: @Shashanth I already managed to solve the problem but now says (permission denied)

Comment: If your testing device's Android version is API 23 (Marshmallow) or greater, you need to ask runtime permissions (READ_STORAGE in your case) then only you can access files from storage. For more refer to official [doc](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) here

Comment: @Shashanth I already did that on manifest and the error still is there

Comment: If your device's API level is 23 or greater, you also need to ask **RUN-TIME PERMISSIONS**. Adding permissions to the manifest file is not enough. Please check the link I posted in my previous comment. Or check this link https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: Now i have a question. How can I get thisAvtivity on arrayAdapter @Shashanth